# Pandas max dayofyear by year

Tags: pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a datetimeindex. There are multiple observations on the same day but different times.

I'm familiar with the dayofyear attribute.  Is there a way to use this attribute to also determine the max dayofyear by year?  The result would be something like:

```
2015 252
2016 250
2017 251
```

Comment: can you provide a sample data?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you want to look at a list of dates and for each year get the maximum date for that year.

```
 # Sample data
 df = pd.DataFrame({'date':pd.DatetimeIndex(start=pd.datetime(2018,12,24),end=pd.datetime(2019,1,2),freq='h')})
 df['dayofyear'] = df.date.dt.dayofyear
 df['year'] = df.date.dt.year
 df.groupby('year').dayofyear.max()
```

Out:

```
 year
 2018    365
 2019      2
```